# I am receiving internet connection from my modem but not from my routers across my house

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, modem

So my modem (technicolor TG588iv) is getting a connection alright. So when I connect it via LAN with my PC it works just fine, but the routers I have (NETGEAR WG102) don't give any WI-FI connection to my PC, even when plugged in directly with my modem. I have already:

Looked at the DHCP of both the routers and the modem which seem to be the same and i have already done a full factory reset of my main router and the only thing that happened was that the router "split" into 2 the main-router one and another which is an open router but works perfectly fine when it comes to WI-FI.

If anyone has any idea it would be a lifesaving.

Comment: Does your modem provide Wireless?  and is that conflicting with the routers trying to do wireless?

Comment: Are the LAN interfaces all on different subnets? Also, why are you running multiple routers? Roaming would work better with the secondary routers converted to access points - and running the same Said/password on all of them [on different channels]

Comment: Please provide a diagram on how the devices are connected and how they are configured.

Comment: @John my modem does not provide any wireless connection.

Comment: @davidgo basically i have one main-router and other subrouters that have the same settings as the main one.

Comment: @Albin my modem is connected to my homes fixed line network and my routers are connected to the power jack via LAN adapter.

Comment: @HandsomeBanana you do know what a diagram is, right? your comment does not really help. Impossible to do the troubleshooting on such limited info (unless you want to play the guessing game).

Answer (score 0):

"Basically I have 1 main router and all the subrouters have the same settings as the main one"... There is your problem.

Your sub-routers are being assigned an IP address in their LAN range on their WAN.

A skmple - but not very sophisticated  - way to fix your network wpuld be to change the LAN range so its different on each router. . You can replace 192.168.1.1 with 10.0.x.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 where x is a different number between 0 and 254 for each sub-router.

A better, but more complex solution is to scrap the additional routers and turn them into APs so you only have 1 rputer.  How you do this depends a bit on your model, but it typically means disabling DHCP on the router and ignoring the WAN interface (plug the network cable into a LAN interface).   If you then set the same SSID, password and authentication type for each device - while specifying a different - ideally non-overlapping - wifi channel, you will get seemless roaming.